# Bold italic \varkappa in STIX 2

Tags: unicode-math, stix, math-fonts

While testing the STIX 2.0 fonts with `unicode-math`, I got a very strange `\varkappa` in bold italic font. Here it is a quick example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{luaotfload}  %% only active when using LuaTeX
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}

\begin{document}
\[
\symup{\varkappa} \quad
\symit{\varkappa} \quad
\symbfup{\varkappa} \quad
\symbfit{\varkappa}
\]
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Why this could happen? (I'm using TeXStudio 2.11.2 on Windows 10. The result is the same either using XeTeX or LuaTeX.)

Comment: looks like a bug to me, you could report it to stix..

Comment: Apparently, they put the wrong glyph at slot U+1D752 MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC KAPPA SYMBOL. It's correct in STIX Math. The symbol looks like a KOPPA.

Comment: I'm using the STIX Math font, though...

Comment: @egreg meant it was correct in the original Stix, this is a new bug introduced in v2

Comment: I added a ticket at https://sourceforge.net/p/stixfonts/tracking/79/

Comment: Thank you egreg! I was actually wondering how one could notify this to STIpub...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a wrong glyph in slot U+1D752 MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC KAPPA SYMBOL (possibly somebody mistook KOPPA for KAPPA).

Until the bug is fixed, you can get away with the symbol from STIX Math version 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont[range="1D752]{STIX Math}

\begin{document}
\[
\symup{\varkappa} \quad
\symit{\varkappa} \quad
\symbfup{\varkappa} \quad
\symbfit{\varkappa}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for recognising the koppa, although it's easier for you as you no doubt recall the original  Phoenician.